# How many lightning components can be added to a lightning app?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-experience, salesforce1-app

I did not find it in the documentation. How many lightning components can be added to a lightning application?

Thanks!

Comment: While there might be a practical memory/performance limit, I don't imagine there is any hard-coded limit. Why do you ask?

Comment: Thank you. I just saw this question somewhere. So I asked. Thanks for your reply.